# Why is the binary search function throwing an error?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

I am trying to search for a long long int using the binary_search function, but the function is throwing an error which I cannot interpret. Could you help me with this problem?

I am using code :: blocks and C ++ 11.

```
Erro: ..error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(const Client&, const Client&)>) (const int&, Client&)'|
```

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class Client{
public:
    int id;
    std::string name;
    long long int number;

};

int main()
{
    long long int s_num; // Edited. It was a mistake when typing here in the post.

    std::vector<Client> vCli =
    {
        { 1, "Stive", 68020899020 },
        { 2, "Anna",  13389155032 },
        { 3, "Olly",  32911233288 },
    };

    std::sort(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), [](const Client &c1, const Client &c2) { return c1.number < c2.number; });

    for (Client c : vCli) //print test
        std::cout << c.id << " - " << c.name << " - " << c.number << std::endl;


    s_num = 13389155032; // Anna's number

    bool yesNumber = std::binary_search( vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_num,
                               []( const Client &c1, const Client &c2)
                                {
                                    return c1.number > c2.number;
                                } );


    yesNumber ? std::cout << "\nClient found.\n" : std::cout << "\nClient NOT found.\n" ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does 13389155032 fit into int on your platform?

Comment: @ÖöTiib You'd have to go quite far back in time to find one for which it doesn't.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am studying programming, I have many doubts. And honestly, I can't answer that question. I was studying other codes and implementations and made this example code.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I believe so.

Comment: @DiegoHilário I understand. I hope you understand you're actually doing two different things. In the first operation (sort), you built a comparator for ordering `Client`s. That was well done, and that lambda comparator a good fit for that task. In the second, however, you asking for something different. You're looking for *value* equivalence based on something that *isn't* a `Client` ; it's an `int`. The same comparator won't work there. You'll need something different. Unrelated, `s_num` should be the same type as your `number` member. Won't fix your problem but will fix an important warning.

Comment: Godbolts `int` is 32 bits - and won't be able to house 13389155032 - but even if it did, there's no good reason to make it an `int` when you search for a `long long int`.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica most platforms that I program in C++ for have 32 bit ints.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I understand, but these are `long long int`s.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the clarification. I'm 2 days trying to make it work, but I can't. I think I understand your explanation, but even using the code provided in the answer below, which follows the assumptions you explained, I can't compile. Could you help me with a practical example.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica no, s_num  was edited to long long int from int just recently.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I apologize. It was a typo, but the problem persists.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Okay but `Client::number` was `long long int` from the start.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type T can be implicitly converted to both Type1 and Type2

In your case, `T=int` and `int` can not be implicitly converted to `Client`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It could help with a practical example. I already understand what are different types, but I am not seeing a solution for this conversion ... Newbie in programming, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda implements the wrong comparison.

You're asking `std::binary_search` to find the integer `s_num` within a collection of `Client`s, but you're only telling it how to sort `Client`s.

It needs a function that compares `Client`s to `long long int`s.

Taking an educated guess at your requirements, that means:

```
bool yesNumber = std::binary_search( vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_num,
    [](const Client &c, const long long int val)
    {
        return c.number > val;
    }
 );
```

I'm actually not sure that this is sufficient, though; you may need to provide a functor that can compare `Client`s and `long long int`s in both directions (i.e. one with which you can swap the arguments). I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader, but I can tell you that a lambda isn't going to do the job.

Comment: @LightRacesWithMonica Thank you for your help. Actually, the code was not compiled. I'm two days trying to make it work and I can't. :D

Comment: Yep, see the last paragraph. Can't do it _all_ for you, as that would be no fun ;)

Comment: Not fun for me either LOL..Just like a practical example. I can't leave the place in two days. : D

Answer (score 0):

You have sorted the vector in the opposite order as you tell it when you use `std::binary_search` which will make the search fail.

And as pointed out, you use a type not implicitly convertible to a `Client`.

Consider adding constructors:

```
Client(int Id, const std::string& Name, long long int Number) :
    id(Id), name(Name), number(Number) 
{}
Client(long long int x) : id{}, name{}, number(x) {}
```

And then provide the correct comparator (`<`) in the binary search:

```
long long int s_num = 13389155032;

bool yesNumber = std::binary_search( vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_num,
    [](const Client& c1, const Client c2) {
        return c1.number < c2.number;
    }
);
```

Alternatively, create a `Client` that you use for searching:

```
Client s_num{{}, {}, 13389155032};

bool yesNumber = std::binary_search(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_num,
    [](const Client& c1, const Client& c2) { 
        return c1.number < c2.number; 
    }
);
```

Comment: It was a typo about INT. Thanks for the correction. Would there be a way without the need for a builder? thank you

Comment: @DiegoHilário You are weclcome. The most important part was about the sorting though because that won't give you a compilation error, but your binary search will fail in runtime instead. What do you mean by "_builder_"? Do you mean the converting constructor?  Sure, create a `Client` and use that for searching - added that as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here. One would be to define a constructor that will let you implicitly create a `Client` from a `long long int`.

Another would be to define comparison between `long long int` and `Client`. The tricky point here is that you need to be prepared to handle expressions like either: `long long < Client` or `Client < long long`. There are a couple of ways you could do that. One would be to define a comparison class that has overloads for both directions:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(long long int a, Client const &b) {
        return a < b.number;
    }

    bool operator()(Client const &a, long long int b) {
        return a.number < b;
    }
};
```

Then pass an instance of that in the call to binary_search:

```
bool yesNumber = std::binary_search( vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_num, cmp());
```

Another possibility would be to define a pair of `getKey` functions, one for a `long long`, and one for a `Client`:

```
class Client { 
// ...

    friend long long getKey(Client const &a) { return a.number; }
};

long long getKey(long long a) { return a; }
```

...then write your lambda like this:

```
[](auto const &a, auto const &b) { return getKey(a) < getKey(b); }
```

This way, whenever a comparison is done using the template, a type is assigned to each of `a` and `b`, and that type is used to select which overload of `getKey` will be called for that parameter. Kind of roundabout, but it does work.

Yet another possibility would be to define the comparison inside of your `Client` class itself:

```
class Client { 
// ...

    // will be used for sorting:
    bool operator<(Client const &other) const { return number < other.number; }

    // will be used for searching:
    bool operator<(long long val) const { return number < val; }
    friend operator<(long long val, Client const &c) { return val < c.number; }
};
```

In this case, we don't need to specify anything about comparison when we do the sorting or searching:

```
// Each of these will automatically use Client::operator<
std::sort(vCli.begin(), vCli.end());

bool yesNumber = std::binary_search(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_num);
```

One final point: your use of the ternary operator is a bit unusual, to say the least. Typically you use it to yield one of two values, which is then used in an expression. If you just want to execute on of two expressions, depending on whether an expression is true or false, you'd normally use an `if`/`else` to do it. So the obvious choices would be either:

```
std::cout << (yesNumber ? "\nClient found.\n" : "\nClient NOT found.\n");
```

...or else:

```
if (yesNumber) {
    std::cout << "\nclient found.\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "\nClient NOT found.\n";
}
```

Note the parentheses in the first case--they're necessary because `<<` has higher precedence than the ternary operator. Without them, the statement would be parsed as:

```
(std::cout << yesNumber) ? "\nClient found.\n" : "\nClient NOT found.\n";
```

So it would just write `yesNumber` out to `cout`, then use the return from `cout` to select between the `found`/`NOT found` strings, but not put that result to any use.

Comment: Thanks for the help, friend. Your explanation and code are very professional. I will study it line by line. It will contribute a lot to my learning.